# How do I get close to 1600x1600 resolution with dual monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a pair of 1440 x 900 monitors that I want to run in portrait mode (not mirrored).

When I select 800 x 600 for both, it works, but I am not near the maximum of the monitor hardware nor am I near what appears to be the addressable space of 1600 x 1600.

If I select 1280 x 800 for both, I get the following error:

```
The selected configuration could not be applied:
requested position/size for CRTC 148 is outside the allowed limit: 
position=(800,0), size=(1280,800), maximum=(1600,1600).
```

Superficially it appears this error is a bug.  A pair of 800 pixels side by side (when in portrait) does not exceed 1600, and of course 1280 does not exceed it.

How can I get this to work.  Of course I would prefer a pair set to 1440 x 900 which is the actual LCD resolution, but then of course the 900 side by side pair would total 1800 and so I won't even bother with that.

The correct rotation setting seems to be "counterclockwise".  I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and a Radeon HD 5450 and the Catalyst 11.12 for x86-64 architecture.  I am dual booting.  I had no complaints with the visual quality on Windows 7, it looked good and used the natural resolution (1440 x 900) even in portrait.  Thus it seems safe to conclude the hardware can do it but Ubuntu and the driver for Ubuntu is at fault.

Although it would be a shame to do so given the Windows 7 example, I would be willing to buy a new video card if a card and driver combination successfully displays dual monitors in 1440 x 900 (each) non-mirrored portrait on Ubuntu 11.10.  Please post a comment if you have this working.  At this point I would even consider landscape non-mirrored dual monitors.

Comment: Have you tried 800 x 1280 instead? From the output it looks like you are adding a normal screen to a rotated one, and 800 + 1280 > 1600.

Comment: There is no 800 x 1280 choice.  It's 1280 x 800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the virtual resolution by editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf in the Screen section on the Virtual line.  Example:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Virtual 2880 2880
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

[helpful information on the virtual screen at this link](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2#the_Virtual_screen)

At the link it says making the virtual screen square makes rotation easy.  By setting it to 2880 x 2880 I was able to get both 1440 x 900 monitors into portrait mode using the System > Preferences > Monitors tool.  Unfortunately after getting into this mode, paring back to the minimum such as 1800 x 1440 (assuming side by side portrait 900 x 1440) and rebooting resulted in an error message.  The reverse ordering of dimensions, 1440 x 1800, also resulted in an error.  Leaving it at 2880 x 2880 seems wasteful but at least it works.